# Can this set of points be called a geometric shape?

Tags: geometry

If I have a graph $G = (V, E): V \subset R^2, E \subset (R^2, R^2)$, can its visual representation be called a geometric shape if it has edges that are fully enclosed within the minimum area hull of $V$? I can't find a subclass of geometric shapes that include such structures, since those definitely can't be called polygons.

An example of the graph would be:

[image: A graph]

Comment: Do you have some particular definition of the phrase "geometric shape" in mind?

Comment: Do you perhaps look for *planar graphs*? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph

Comment: @LeeMosher The wikipedia definition is fine, and the structures seem to satisfy that definition. But I falied to find a subsategory of geometric shapes that more precisely defines such structures, and because of that I assume I might be wrong.

Comment: @Berci I'm familiar with planar graphs, but graphs aren't shapes, right? They're objects and connections between objects, and their spacial visualisations are separate from them, when geometric shapes are spacial visualisations, e.g. of a cyclic graph. I'm curious about the spacial thing.

Comment: The wikipedia entry for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_shape does not give a mathematical definition of the phrase "geometric shape". Instead it gives a mathematical definition of the **relation** "same shape" between subsets of the plane, defining that relation to be the same as what is usually called "similarity". But your question is not about relations between objects, so the Wikipedia entry is irrelevant. So you still need to give a definition.

Comment: @LeeMosher Isn't there a commonly accepted definition for a geometric shape? I assumed it is a strict enough term.

Comment: No, that's the problem, there isn't. It's a rather vague term. So it's hard for anyone to answer your question, because we don't know what *you* mean by geometric shape.

Comment: @LeeMosher I didn't know that, I guess then my question doesn't make sense. Thanks for making it clear.